# How can I grab this with RegEx?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have this:

```
<li class="one"><strong>String here: </strong><span class="one">&nbsp;
                                 <!--googleoff: all--> 
                                 <strong>STRING TO GRAB</strong> 
                                 <!--googleon: all--> 
                                 </span></li>
```

How can I grab the `STRING TO GRAB` efficiently with RegEx? Keep in mind that this isn't the only text on the page, so `/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/` wouldn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You need another *anchor point*. Are the `google` comments always around it?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. I imagine so, but I haven't done any thorough research. I'll open some other browsers and start checking.

Comment: Yes, they do seem to be always there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways.

**Dom classes**: use the dom classes of PHP if the html is sort of a decent kind.

See: 
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

**Regex**
 If it's not really valid html or dom loading does not work, perhaps regex is a good solution.

I'm assuming that the <!--googleoff: all--> is always present, this might work, if not, perhaps you can supply some more comments on the specificity of the string:

```
$string = "yourhtmlstring";
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<!--googleoff: all-->\s+?<strong>(.+)<\/strong>\s+?<!--googleon: all-->/', $string, $matches)
var_dump($matches);
```

**Final tip**
To test the regex further: http://tinyurl.com/6gy6584

Answer (score 0):

As said on the other answer, regex isn't the best answer for html (or xml)

```
/<strong>(.+?)<\/strong>/
```

Note the `?` which makes the regex non greedy